# When shouldn't we use Centroid-based classifiers?

Tags: classification, k-nearest-neighbour

I understand that Certroid-based classifiers are better than k-NNs.

> 13.5.1.2 Centroid-Based Classiﬁcation
>
> Centroid-based classiﬁcation is a fast alternative to k-nearest neighbor classiﬁers. The basic idea is
>   to use an oﬀ-the-shelf clustering algorithm to partition the documents
>   of each class into clusters. The number of clusters derived from the
>   documents of each class is proportional to the number of documents in
>   that class... ... ... ... ..., this approach also indirectly addresses the
>   issues of synonymy and polysemy, with the additional advantage that the k-nearest neighbor
>   classiﬁcation can be performed more eﬃciently with a smaller number of centroids. The
>   dominant label from the top-k matching centroids, based on cosine similarity, is reported.
>   Such an approach can provide comparable or better accuracy than the vanilla k-nearest
>   neighbor classiﬁer in many cases.

This is quoted from "*Data Mining: The Textbook*" by Charu C. Aggarwal. Page-447-48.

But, **When shouldn't we use Centroid-based classifiers as opposed to Nearest Neighbors?**

My teacher told me something about **Biases** which I don't remember well.

Comment: "I understand that Certroid-based classifiers are better than k-NNs." - what do you mean with "better"?? Accuracy or computation time?

Comment: @stats0007, I understand what is written in Aggarwal's book.